# How to get value from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-props

I have an react app, and using redux and props to get array of objects into my component, and i am getting them. But i can't access particular property inside of one of objects that are in that array.

With this:

```
console.log(this.props.users)
```

[image]
I get listed array with all objects inside it. But when i need to access particular object or property of that object, for example:

```
console.log(this.props.users[0])
console.log(this.props.users[0].name)
```

I am getting error:

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

But when I iterate through array with map() method i have access to it, it works. Why can't i access it normally?

Comment: please post console output for the first console statemet

Comment: What does your array of objects look like?

Comment: can you please show us the users object structure ?

Comment: What does `console.log(this.props.users)` show?

Comment: You are either not connecting your component to the store correctly or, if `props.users` is loaded asynchronously, you may be trying to access an entry in an array that has not loaded yet. Post your component code.

Comment: @Max but i can access all data, i just can't get particular object or property, look at the my console log

Comment: @bobby Are you calling `console.log` in the render method? Is users loaded asynchronously?

Comment: @Max yea i am calling it in render method, and they are loaded asynchronously

Comment: @bobby. Can you share how the users are being passed in to props for this component. Are you getting the users from a redux state, or are you passing them in through a higher-order-component

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access properties of `this.props.users` before it has loaded. Your component renders without waiting for your data to fetch. When you `console.log(this.props.users)` you say that you get an array, but above that, it probably logs `undefined` at least once when the component renders before `this.props.users` has loaded.

You have a couple of options. You can either do this at the very top of your render method to prevent the rest of the code in the method from executing:

```
if (!this.props.users) return null;
```

Once the data is fetched and props change, the render method will be called again.

The other option is to declare a default value, of an empty array for `users` in your reducer.

Comment: i have an empty array in reducer and it didnt work with that either, but with first option that you said it works

Comment: @bobby If that's the case, you are likely overwriting the default value for users somewhere before they're fetched.

Comment: how i declare default value for a array of objects? if i just put arrayofObjects = [ ], first time when app renders arrayOfObjects.object.someProperty it will throw error that it can't read property of undefined

Comment: It is difficult to define deeply nested default values. In that case `_.get` from lodash is a good solution. `_.get(arrayOfObjects, 'object.someProperty', 'banana')` will return a default value (the 3rd arg) instead of throwing an error. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get

Answer (score 1):

Might be when you are executing that line `this.props.users` is undefined. Check the flow where you have added `console.log(this.props.users[0])`

Comment: but at the same point i can list in console whole array with console.log(this.props.users)

Comment: @bobby Can you access `this.props.users.length`?

Comment: @Bergi no i can't

Comment: @bobby Can you `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.users))`? My guess is that your console log doesn't actually come from the line you thought it came

Comment: @bergi I did that and i got result in console...max have a right answer

Answer (score 0):

```
const App = () => {
  
  const example = () => {
    const data =[{id:1 ,name: "Users1", description: "desc1"}, 
                {id:2 ,name: "Users2", description: "desc2"}];
    return (
      <div>
      {data.map(function(cValue, idx){
          console.log("currentValue.id:",cValue.id);
          console.log("currentValue.name:",cValue.name);
          console.log("currentValue.description:",cValue.description);
         return (<li key={idx}>name = {cValue.name} description = {cValue.description}</li>)
      })}
      </div>
      );
    }

  return(
    <p style = {{color:'white'}}>
      {example()}
    </p>
  );
}

export default App;
```